# Empty image in swipeActions (tableView)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, action

I am trying to add a custom `UIImage` for swiping actions in my table view. My image exists (I can see them when defining my variable) but when running my app, I just have a white circle but not an orange flag. It looks like the content of the image (but not the shape) is missing.

```
@available(iOS 11, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let molecule = moleculesWithSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        var favouriteStatus: NSNumber!
        var image: UIImage!

        if molecule.isFavorite == true {
            favouriteStatus = false
            image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unflagged")
        }
        else {
            favouriteStatus = true
            image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "flagged")
        }

        let flagAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, handler) in
            molecule.isFavorite = favouriteStatus
            tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
            MoleculeStore.shared().saveChanges()
            //self.reloadSections()
            print(handler(true))
        }

        flagAction.image = image
        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [flagAction])
        configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return configuration
    }
```

Here is what I get:
[image]

Would anyone have an idea of what is going on? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, is your issue resolved ? if so pls update your answer. am in the same situation

Answer (score -1):

You might be using a template rendering. Use original:

```
image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unflagged").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

and

```
image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "flagged").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: Seems that unfortunately iOS enforces template rendering